# what is the use of callback in spotify?

Tags: spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to authenticate to spotify using python (spotipy).
Anyway I couldn't find an explanation up to now about which role plays the callback URI.
How does it have to look like and where must it be located when I use https://localhost:8888/callback?
The server is started by using "node (%app_path%/)app.js".

Thanks for any help

Comment: ...sorry, I'm using windows 10.